# Activiti REST API: complete process instance

Tags: spring-boot, activiti

I am working with Activiti 5 REST API interfaceintegrated with Spring Boot Activiti Starterand I am trying to complete a process instance. I was able to instantiate a process definition, walk through the process instance tasks and complete each of them. It correctly works until the end of the process, when there are no pending tasks left. I would expect the process instance to be completed - i.e. completed: true-, as I have an end event (terminateEventDefinition), but it is not.
I could not find the REST Api to complete the process instance. So, what's the correct way of managing process instance completion?
Thanks.

Comment: Please provide your process-definition.xml here. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I am missing something, but after the last task is completed the process will end normally and no longer visible in the /runtime/process-instances list.
Now, you mention that you complete the instance with a Terminate End Event, Terminate End events will complete the instance but will not set the "complete" flag. Terminate is typically used for cancelling a running process.
Instead of terminate, you should use a regular end event, this should set the complete flag.

Again, maybe I am missing somethign in your description.
Thanks
Greg